# C# GetHashCode with two Int16, also returns only up to Int32?

Tags: c#, hash, int, gethashcode, int32

Sorry to combine two questions into one, they are related.

`HashCode`s for `HashSet`s and the such. As I understand it, they must be unique, not change, and represent any configuration of an object as a single number.

My first question is that for my object, containing the two Int16s `a` and `b`, is it safe for my `GetHashCode` to return something like `a * n + b` where n is a large number, I think perhaps `Math.Pow(2, 16)`?

Also `GetHashCode` appears to inflexibly return specifically the type Int32.

32bits can just about store, for example, two Int16s, a single unicode character or 16 N, S, E, W compass directions, it's not much, even something like a small few node graph would probably be too much for it. Does this represent a limit of C# Hash collections?

Comment: I'd use `(a << 16) | b` which happens to be unique and does no complex math

Comment: It isn't unique, you are forgetting about sign extension.  (a << 16) | (b & 0xffff) is unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As I understand it, they must be unique

Nope. They can't possibly be unique for most types, which can have more than 2<sup>32</sup> possible values. Ideally, if two objects have the same hash code then they're *unlikely* to be equal - but you should never assume that they *are* equal. The important point is that if they have *different* hash codes, they should definitely be *unequal*.

> My first question is that for my object, containing the two Int16s a and b, is it safe for my GetHashCode to return something like a * n + b where n is a large number, I think perhaps Math.Pow(2, 16).

If it *only* contains two `Int16` values, it would be simplest to use:

```
return (a << 16) | (ushort) b;
```

Then the value *will* be unique. Hoorah!

> Also `GetHashCode` appears to inflexibly return specifically the type `Int32`.

Yes. Types such as `Dictionary` and `HashSet` need to be able to use the fixed size so they can work with it to put values into buckets.

> 32bits can just about store, for example, two Int16s, a single unicode character or 16 N, S, E, W compass directions, it's not much, even something like a small few node graph would probably be too much for it. Does this represent a limit of C# Hash collections?

If it *were* a limitation, it would be a .NET limitation rather than a C# limitation - but no, it's just a misunderstanding of what hash codes are meant to represent.

Eric Lippert has an excellent (obviously) [blog post about `GetHashCode`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx) which you should read for more information.

Comment: Thanks for a clear answer. They don't have to be unique? So it could "return 0;" and it would still work, if inefficiently?

Comment: @alan2here: Yes. Returning a constant is always a valid strategy for a hash code - but one which defeats all the normal efficiencies associated with hash tables etc.

Comment: ", if two objects have the same hash code then they're <strike>un</strike>likely to be equal - but you should never assume that they are <strike>un</strike>equal" You messed up this sentence a bit

Comment: So the hash code is a sort of numerical estimate for similarity. Also I'm getting "Bitwise-or operator used on a sign-extended operand; consider casting to a smaller unsigned type first" warning on "return (a << 16) | b;", I'm ignoring it for now.

Comment: @alan2here: No, not an estimate of similarity - two very similar values could have very different hash codes. *All* that the value represents is potential equality. And yes, you can ignore the warning - which I assume is from ReSharper?

Comment: I have no Visual Studio mods. Potential equality, ty :¬)

Comment: Jon, as Hans Passant reminded Marc Gravell in comments on the question, @alan2here *should not* ignore that warning.  If he does, for any negative `b` value, all `a, b` pairs will have the same hash code, regardless of the value of a.  If b is less than zero, `((a << 16) | b) == b`, because of sign extension.

Comment: Thanks phoog. I've added the bracketed UInt16.

Answer (score 1):

`GetHashCode` is not (and cannot be) unique for every instance of an object. Take `Int64`, for example; even if the hash function is perfectly distributed, there will be <strike>two</strike> *four billion* `Int64`s that hash to every value, since the hash code is, as you mentioned, only an `Int32`.

However this is not a limitation on collections using hash codes; they are simply use buckets for elements which hash to the same value. So a lookup into a hash table isn't guaranteed to be a single operation. Getting the correct bucket is a single operation, but there may be multiple items in that bucket.

Comment: If the hash function is well distributed then of course there will be *four billion* collisions per 32 bit hash.

Comment: Not 2 `Int64`s per `Int32` hash value, but 4294967296.  2^64 / 2^32 equals 2^32.

Comment: @EricLippert, phoog: of course you're correct. Something in my brain saw 32 and 64 and automatically went to 64/32 rather than 2^64/2^32...